# What is the difference between to use org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client Vs com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2 on dataflow gcp

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, hbase, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-bigtable

There are a difference of perfomance o stability, or long term support maybe ?. I mean is needed migrate hbase api to big table connector apache beam.

Answer (score 2):

The package [org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-client/javadoc/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/package-summary) is an [HBase client for Java](https://hbase.apache.org/) while [com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2](https://cloud.google.com/java/docs/reference/google-cloud-bigtable/latest/com.google.cloud.bigtable.data.v2) is a Cloud Bigtable data API client.

[Cloud Bigtable](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-PH-all-en-dr-skws-all-all-trial-e-dr-1009882&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_468768400460-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20SKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Databases%20%7E%20Cloud%20Bigtable_big%20data-big%20table-KWID_43700024746630443-kwd-317056130768&userloc_9067371-network_g&utm_term=KW_cloud%20bigtable&gclid=CjwKCAjwzNOaBhAcEiwAD7Tb6DMXmz76h5QOcxkHDmxAbXz5HQmPdJKbReRWJXnCutAEwNnAu2oS3BoCGK0QAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds) is a NoSQL database but not an open-source project. A connection with Apache HBase library for Java can integrate Cloud Bigtable with [Apache Hadoop](https://hadoop.apache.org/)/Apache Hbase and adapts to existing Apache ecosystem.
Apache Hbase is one of the many tools and application that Apache Hadoop included to collect, store, analyze, and manage big data.

You can refer to this SO [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24860516/what-it-the-difference-between-hbase-and-bigtable) to view the answers of the question which is related to yours. Also, you may look up to this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/hbase-differences#column_families) for more information about their differences.